# .js and .css files are loading as text/html in my JSP page.

Tags: javascript, jsp, mime-types, tomcat7, vaadin

When I load my jsp page, the attached css and js files are rendered as text/html format. 
I noticed it from chrome browser where I could see this error message

"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html"

I have specified the mime type in web.xml as follows,

```
    <mime-mapping>    
        <extension>js</extension>        
        <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>        
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>    
        <extension>css</extension>        
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>        
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>    
        <extension>jpg</extension>        
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>        
    </mime-mapping>
```

The server where I am running my application is Apache Tomcat 7. I created this JSP file inside the Vaadin Project.

My questions are, 
Should I need to change the Mime type somewhere else in Tomcat configuration ? 
 is there any limitation to include the CSS and JS files in a JSP page?
or Is it because of Vaadin framework?

I am just a beginner trying to learn JSP and vaadin framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the reason for this issue. I just fixed web.xml by changing the default url mapping

eg. 
from the default value as below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After changing this I still got an error which I fixed by adding

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>My Application</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

which is covered in the Book of Vaadin, section 4.8
https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.environment.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a filter in my `web.xml` that filters everything. (It redirects to a certain page based on the IP address.)

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

With this filter mapping, all requests (including images, stylesheets, scripts, etc.) go through the filter. You can fix it by either removing the `filter-mapping` from your `web.xml` or checking the logic in the `filter-class` to allow or ignore the resources.