# Select2 mimetype error

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use Select2 and Chrome is refusing to execute the script because the mimetype is text/html. I am using 4.0.3. Here is my html:

```
<link href="static/js/common/select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="static/js/common/select2/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/controllers/common/SelectAgency.js"></script>

<select id="auto"></select>
```

The code for SelectAgency.js is this:

```
var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

$("#auto").select2({
 placeholder:'Test'
})
```

The select box appears, but it does not contain anything. Also this message appears in the console

select2.min.js:233 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/foiaonline/action/public/request/static/js/common/select2/js/static/js/controllers/common/select2/css/select2.min.css".

Comment: That message isn't caused by anything you wrote in the code, it's because of the way you're hosting the file. What application are you using to host the .js file?

Comment: I have it stored locally in my eclipse project

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480347/js-and-css-files-are-loading-as-text-html-in-my-jsp-page) might be the solution to that warning you got. I'm not sure if that's going to fix the select box issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older version of select2(3.5.1). In 3.5.1 select2 is initialized with:

```
$(panel).select2({
    placeholder:placeholderStr,
    data: items
});

<input id="panel" type="text", class="auto"/></td>
```